# Setting user credentials on aws instance using jclouds

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, jclouds

I am trying to create an aws instance using `jclouds 1.9.0` and then run a script on it (via ssh). I am following the example locate [here](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/master/compute-basics/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/compute/basics/MainApp.java) but I am getting authentication failed errors when the client (java program) tries to connect at the instance. The AWS console show that instance is up and running.

The example tries to create a LoginCrendentials object

```
String user = System.getProperty("user.name");
String privateKey = Files.toString(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ssh/id_rsa"), UTF_8);
return LoginCredentials.builder().user(user).privateKey(privateKey).build();
```

which is latter used from the ssh client

```
responses = compute.runScriptOnNodesMatching(
                inGroup(groupName),             // predicate used to select nodes
                exec(command),                  // what you actually intend to run
                overrideLoginCredentials(login) // use my local user & ssh key
                        .runAsRoot(false)       // don't attempt to run as root (sudo)
                        .wrapInInitScript(false));
```

Some Login information are injected to the instance with following commands

```
Statement bootInstructions = AdminAccess.standard();
templateBuilder.options(runScript(bootInstructions));
```

Since I am on Windows machine the creation of LoginCrendentials 'fails' and thus I alter its code to

```
String user = "ec2-user";
String privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----.....-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
return  LoginCredentials.builder().user(user).privateKey(privateKey).build();
```

I also to define the credentials while building the template as described in ["EC2: In Depth"](https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/aws-ec2/) guide but with no luck.

An alternative is to build instance and inject the keypair as follows, but this implies that I need to have the ssh key stored in my AWS console, which is not currently the case and also breaks the functionality of running a script (via ssh) since I can not infer the `NodeMetadata` from a `RunningInstance` object.

```
RunInstancesOptions options = RunInstancesOptions.Builder.asType("t2.micro").withKeyName(keypair).withSecurityGroup(securityGroup).withUserData(script.getBytes());
```

Any suggestions??

Note: While I am currently testing this on aws, I want to keep the code as decoupled from the provider as possible.

**Update 26/10/2015**

Based on [@Ignasi Barrera answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33324107/2279200), I changed my implementation by adding `.init(new MyAdminAccessConfiguration())` while creating the `bootInstructions`

```
Statement bootInstructions = AdminAccess.standard().init(new MyAdminAccessConfiguration());
templateBuilder.options(runScript(bootInstructions));
```

Where `MyAdminAccessConfiguration` is my own implementation of the AdminAccessConfiguration interface as @Ignasi Barrera described it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue relies on the fact that the jclouds code runs on a Windows machine and jclouds makes some Unix assumptions by default.

There are two different things here: first, the `AdminAccess.standard()` is used to configure a user in the deployed node once it boots, and later the `LoginCredentials` object passed to the run script method is used to authenticate against the user that has been created with the previous statement.

The issue here is that the `AdminAccess.standard()` reads the "current user" information and assumes a Unix System. That user information is provided by [this Default class](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/compute/src/main/java/org/jclouds/compute/config/AdminAccessConfiguration.java#L46-L54), and in your case I'm pretty sure it will fallback to the `catch` block and return an auto-generated SSH key pair. That means, the `AdminAccess.standard()` is creating a user in the node with an auto-generated (random) SSH key, but the `LoginCredentials` you are building don't match those keys, thus the authentication failure.

Since the `AdminAccess` entity is immutable, the better and cleaner approach to fix this is to create your own implementation of the [AdminAccessConfiguration interface](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/compute/src/main/java/org/jclouds/compute/config/AdminAccessConfiguration.java#L41). You can just copy the entire `Default` class and change the Unix specific bits to accommodate the SSH setup in your Windows machine. Once you have the implementation class, you can inject it by creating a Guice module and passing it to the list of modules provided when creating the jclouds context. Something like:

```java
// Create the custom module to inject your implementation
Module windowsAdminAccess = new AbstractModule() {
   @Override protected void configure() {
      bind(AdminAccessConfiguration.class).to(YourCustomWindowsImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
   }
};

// Provide the module in the module list when creating the context
ComputeServiceContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("aws-ec2")
   .credentials("api-key", "api-secret")
   .modules(ImmutableSet.<Module> of(windowsAdminAccess, new SshjSshClientModule()))
   .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);
```

Comment: I am getting a compiler error "AdminAccessConfiguration cannot be resolved to a variable" at `bind(....`, any suggestions? Or any resources you can point me in?

Comment: It was a typo. The `AdminAccessConfiguration` was missing the `.class`. I've already edited the post.